# Crear componentes propios en wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicacion de prueba que es como tipo red social, estonces estaba creando los modelos de las publicaciones pero yo uso este modelo en bastantes vistas y me parece repetido hacerlo en todas las vistas, entonces mi duda es si se pueden crear componentes en los que pueda insertar propiedades unicas como el texto o la cantidad de likes. Por ejemplo algo asi

```
    <Post title="" likes=""  />
```

Estoy usando MVVM con caliburn micro por si hay alguna manera mas optima de hacerlo con mvvm que con wpf puro.

Comment: No se si entiendo exactamente lo que necesitas. Pero creo que lo que buscas es crear [Propiedades de dependencia personalizadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Quiero crear una etiqueta unica en la que le pase propiedades que sean como el titulo o contenido, nose si conoces reactjs pero ahi tu creas componentes y le puedes pasar propiedades que se pueden usar en el componente. Es dificil de explicar sinceramente

Comment: La parte gráfica reutilizable la puedes conseguir muy fácil con un UserControl personalizado a tu gusto, y sobre las funciones, si estás usando MVVM lo consigues con Properties bien declaradas nomás, la arquitectura propia del framework permite que hagas lo que quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es muy extenso ya que hay diferentes maneras de lograrlo pero de forma resumida, una de las mejores maneras es creando un `UserControl`, en tu caso llamarlo `Post.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Einer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Cantidad de likes" />
        <TextBlock Text="0" Name="CntLikesTxtBlock" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

En tu `Post.xaml.cs`, o code behind, agregas las propieades/metodos que necesitas exponer para utilizarlo en otro control. En este caso expondremos un metodo que recibira el id del usuario para cargar la cantidad de likes:

`Post.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class Post : UserControl
{
   //constructor ..
  
   public async Task CargarLikesAsync(string userid)
   {
        var likes = await CargarLikes(userid);
        // asignamos la cantidad de likes
        this.CntLikesTxtBlock.Text = likes.Cantidad;
   }
  
}
```

Por lo que cuando quieras utilizarlo, solo agregas la refencia del control.
Por ejemplo:

`Home.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Einer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
       <Post x:Name="ThePost"></Post>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Y para cargar los likes solo tendras que obtener la referencia del control y ejecutar el metodo que definimos:

`Home.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class Home : UserControl
{
    public Home()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        Loaded += Home_Loaded;
    }
    
    public void Home_Loaded(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    
        string userid = ObtenerIdUsuarioLogueado();
        ThePost.CargarLikesAsync(userid);
    }
  
}
```